# Java inheritance ArrayList type in method

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, types

I am creating a subclass BClass of my class AClass. AClass has a method which takes an ArrayList of type AClass as its input. I can then not use this method with an ArrayList of type BClass. I understand why this is, but I don't know how to do it right. Can I cast the whole ArrayList to type AClass?

My code is more complex, but this example shows the basic problem:

```
class AClass{
  public float f;
  public AClass(float fstart){
    f = fstart;
  }
  public void setf(ArrayList<AClass> aList){
    for(AClass ax : aList) f += ax.f;
  }
}

class BClass extends AClass{
  public BClass(float fstart){
    super(fstart);
  }
}

AClass a1 = new AClass(1.1);
AClass a2 = new AClass(1.2);
AClass a3 = new AClass(1.3);
BClass b1 = new BClass(2.1);
BClass b2 = new BClass(2.2);
BClass b3 = new BClass(2.3);

ArrayList<AClass> aList = new ArrayList<AClass>();
aList.add(a2); aList.add(a3);
a1.setf(aList);

ArrayList<BClass> bList = new ArrayList<BClass>();
bList.add(b1); bList.add(b2); bList.add(b3);
a2.setf(bList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `setf` expects an `ArrayList<AClass>`, not an `ArrayList<BClass>`. An `ArrayList<BClass>` does **not** extend an `ArrayList<AClass>`.

Since an instance of `BClass` is also effectively an `AClass` due to inheritance, then you can simply declare the second list to be of type `ArrayList<AClass>` as well and pass it to the method:

```
ArrayList<AClass> bList = new ArrayList<AClass>();  // instead of BClass
bList.add(b1);
bList.add(b2);
bList.add(b3);
a2.setf(bList);
```

If the second list must only contain `BClass` objects, a better solution would be to define the `setf` method to take an `ArrayList` that contains elements of any subtype of `AClass`, by using a generic wildcard in the parameter:

```
class AClass {
    public float f;

    public AClass(float fstart) {
       f = fstart;
    }

    // TODO consider using List instead of ArrayList
    public void setf(ArrayList<? extends AClass> aList) {
       for(AClass ax : aList) f += ax.f;
    }
}

...

ArrayList<BClass> bList = new ArrayList<BClass>();
bList.add(b1);
bList.add(b2);
bList.add(b3);
a2.setf(bList);
```